# How to run python script using already existing docker image in VSCode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I already have some docker images, I want to run them with different python scripts in VSCode.

How to proceed ??

Thank you

Comment: Please explain further what you are trying to do. Do you want to run a python script inside a docker container or do you want to run images by using a python script? Whats the concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docker image that you have as a interpreter and run/debug anything you want on them.

How to do it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers